# Doubts on application structure and communication directions

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I'm currently building a CQS-style DDD-application. I'm having some doubts on how all 'components' work with each other.

But first I'll give a brief overview about the application's structure:

```
ApplicationService 
  -> Receives command objects 
  -> doesn't return any results
  -> Acts on Domain model
  -> Speaks with Aggregate repository for domain modifications

QueryService
  -> Bypasses domain model; doesn't speak with Aggregate Repositories
  -> Executes queries against database to populate view
  -> Returns 'Representation' objects

REST Controller
  -> Receives HTTP requests and binds 'body content' & request params to Command objects
  -> delegates to ApplicationService for POST, PUT & DELETE requests
  -> Always returns at least some HTTP code
  -> delegates to QueryService for GET requests

Infrastructure
 -> Handles persistence to DB
 -> Contains some scheduling operations
 -> Handles foreign domain events our domain model is 'interested' in

'Open Host'
  -> This is mainly a Facade to be used by other domains
  -> Facade delegates methods to ApplicationService for domain modifications and to QueryService for data retrieval (bypassing Repositories)
```

My Questions:

1. Is it OK that a `DomainEventHandler` corresponds with a `Repository` and invokes some methods on a `Aggregate`? Or should it always correspond with an `ApplicationService`?
2. `QueryService` returns '`Representation`' objects. These are used by UI AND by `'Open Host' Facade` as return value. Is it OK these objects are reused as return value by `Facade`? Or should `Facade` create their own Objects, even the results are basically the same?
3. `ApplicationService` takes '`Commands`' as input parameters. Is it OK these `Commands` are also used by the `Open Host Facade`? Or should the `Facade` only accept primitive values and convert them to `Commands` when delegating to `ApplicationService`?
4. `DomainEventHandlers` seem to reside on '`Infrastructure`' layer. Is it possible that an `ApplicationService` or `Domain Service` also subscribes to an `Domain Event`? Or is this always an `Infrastructure` responsibility?

All advice is very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it OK that a DomainEventHandler corresponds with a Repository and invokes some methods on a Aggregate? Or should it always correspond with an ApplicationService?

In my experience, any handlers are application services.

> QueryService returns 'Representation' objects. These are used by UI AND by 'Open Host' Facade as return value. Is it OK these objects are reused as return value by Facade? Or should Facade create their own Objects, even the results are basically the same?

There is a *lot* of discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778125/open-host-service-vs-application-layer) about the differences between Open Host service and Application Service. It is not clear to me who would be using Open Host service, or why it exists.

> ApplicationService takes 'Commands' as input parameters. Is it OK these Commands are also used by the Open Host Facade? Or should the Facade only accept primitive values and convert them to Commands when delegating to ApplicationService?

I would pass in primitives on the edges of the application and convert them into commands which are then handled in the Application Services

> DomainEventHandlers seem to reside on 'Infrastructure' layer. Is it possible that an ApplicationService or Domain Service also subscribes to an Domain Event? Or is this always an Infrastructure responsibility?

I've always considered my handlers to be Application Services - things that are responsible for orchestrating a user case. So the use case might be "when EventX is received, send an email and update the database". In this example, you would probably consider "the code that sends the email" and "the code that saves to the database" to be *infrastructure* concerns, but the handler itself would not be.

```
public class ExampleHandler : IHandle<ExampleEvent> 
{
    private IRepository _repo;
    private ISendEmails _emailer;

    public ExampleHandler(Repository repo, ISendEmails emailer)
    { 
        .... set the private fields..
    } 

    public void When(ExampleEvent event) 
    {
        _emailer.Send(event.whatever);
        _repo.Save(something);
    }
}
```

To be honest, I don't really think in terms of layers - i prefer a hexagonal architecture style of thinking. In the above example, the event handlers would just have dependencies injected into them and then go about their business.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! About the Open Host Service -> I've implemented this as an interface to be used by other domains. It can be considered as a single 'access point' for cross domain communication. My ApplicationService is only called internally.

Comment: How do the other domains access this? Is it in-process or via http etc? Just wondering if the other domains can use the same messaging infrastructure so all they do is react to messages being published or publish their own messages - might not need an Open Host at all if you can do it this way

Comment: Other domains have 2 possibilities: Or they react on domain events which are asynchronously published; or they correspond with the facade (=open host) for data retrieval or invoke some process. The facade is currently called by plain method invocation; however, in future this will become a REST-service when we'll evolve to a MicroService architecture.

Comment: Ok, sounds sensible. I think you're on the right track